# Android Studio 2.3.2 Gradle Error

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-2.3

I am new to Android Studio, and everything was going fine until I received a nonsense error:

"Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. > Duplicate symbol in table with resource type 'id' and symbol name 'title_conctact'"

I have no idea what it means and I have tried to fix it for two days. I tried uninstalling Android Studio which deleted all my progress, but still, the error remained. Please help, this is annoying. By the way, I am using the latest version 2.3.2.

Comment: did you try invalidate cache and restart

Comment: Yes I tried it twice, but the error is still there.

Comment: check for your jdk and jre

Comment: Where do I look for that?

Comment: in your pc program files>Java

Comment: Yeah they are there and updated. I deleted and re-downloaded everything I needed to use Android Studio.

Comment: Update: Experimenting through the program, inside Android Studio I went to Navigate> Symbol... and then I entered the name of the duplicated symbol, and I found the two symbols. I tried to "Safe Delete", and they were deleted until I ran the program again, and the error came back all the time. I identified where the duplicates are, however, I need to find a way to delete one of them or both of them permanently.

Comment: I dunno if you still have the problem, if you do try this, press ctrl + shift + f and type "title_conctact", see where it appears as a declaration, if it only appears once , then try searching for "title.conctact" , the message you see means that you have declared a symbol that resolves to the same name in two different ways ( dot is replaced by an underscore when generating resources)

Comment: @Cruces you totally saved my ass! "." and "_" was the issue!

Answer (score 1):

hi after finding so much on web i don't get any solution so i tried myself to debug it and i got success to fix this issue you need to find the name in files in your case the name is **title_conctact** so you will get duplicate id's, now you need to rename and make them unique

that's it your problem will be fixed

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The issue I had was due to the keys declared differently in one of my module's resource file and my app's resource file.

In the module's strings.xml file, if you declare the key as 'title.conctact' and in the app's strings.xml file if you declare it as 'title_conctact', then you will face this error.

Changing it to a single format resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Double-clicking `SHIFT` will open a window. Put the **title_conctact** inside the search and you will find the `.xml` file that contains the duplicate id